# Problems with attach database

Tags: sql-server-2008

When I have attach the database, SQL show this error: user `public`does not have permission to run dbcc checkprimaryfile.
How to solve this issue?
Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, when I try to attach database...

Comment: Attach under an admin account?

Comment: Yes, i'm admin.